# Get the first value in an array via index/match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a working formula that needs tweaking.
It is adding up multiple results of dates, but I need just the first one.
Here is the formula

```
 =SUMIF(INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),),">0",B2:E2)
```

[image: jobs and dates they are scheduled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the first date use another INDEX/MATCH instead of SUMIF:

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),)<>"",),0))
```

[image]

---

Or if one has MINIFS():

```
=MINIFS(B2:E2,INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),),">0")
```

This assumes that the date line is sorted in order ascending.

Or if one has the new Dynamic Arrays:

```
=MIN(FILTER(B2:E2,INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),)<>""))
```

for sorted dates or:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:E2,INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),)<>""),0,1)
```

for unsorted or non date titles.

Comment: @PavloKobzar if this answer worked for you please consider marking as correct by cliking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: marked as solved, but another challenge arose. What if I need a reverse search - have a list of jobs scheduled for a particular date? So with an input of "1/22/2020", I get 3 cells: job1, job3, job6.

Comment: @PavloKobzar that is a new question, please post it as such.